# How to initialize the database in sails.js?

Tags: database, node.js, sails.js, waterline

How can I initialize my database in Sails.js? I want to parse some big XML files and insert them into the database, so that my Sails-API can handle the requests.

I would like to insert the data via Waterline and not with the REST API. Is there an opportunity to create management commands (like in Django), so I can do something like `sails init-database` which would run my script that parses the XML and inserts it directly via the Waterline model classes?

I can't use `bootstrap.js` for this kind of task, because I don't want to create the database contents every time sails is lifted. Is there a command line argument, where I can disable running the `bootstrap.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
  Model.count().exec(function (err, count) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    if (count > 0) return cb();

    Model.create(initdata).exec(cb);
  });
};
```

Comment: The global model names are not available in bootstrap in sails 1.x

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap.js for that purpose, simply add some logic in it to test if your XML datas where already inserted. with something like that

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
  MyModelDefinedInXML.find({Afield : "A value I know"}).exec(function(err,res){
  if(err){ //manage it ;}   
  if(res.length>0){
          //skip
          cb();
      }else{
          //perform insert
          cb();
      }
  });
}
```

For dev you simply don't set `sails.config.models.migrate` so if you want to reset everything you can choose option "3" in order to wipe/drop everything in your DB.